# Laravel error 500 with whereHas or Has eloquent methods

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Maybe someone can help with my problem:

when I use some thing like this

```
 $offers = Offer::has( 'author' )->get();
```

I got 500 error with without any detail.

What is interesting, when I use

```
$offers = Offer::has( 'author' )->toSql();
```

it returns correct sql query which works good.

The relationships:

Offer model

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->hasOne( User::class, 'id', 'created_by');
}
```

User model

```
public function offers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Offer::class, 'created_by', 'id' );
}
```

What do you think? thanks.

Comment: Look for the last error in the `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Unfortunately, log is clean, nothing. laravel version is 5.5

Comment: Just use `whereHas` method instead

Comment: @DavidGoloviy, `whereHas` has same problem. the problem fires when executing subquery

Answer (score 0):

I think you got your relationships a bit mixed up. If a User has one offer, then you need to change it to

```
User Model
public function offer () {
    return $this->hasOne(Offer::class, 'created_by');
}

Offer Model
public function author () {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
}
```

Comment: without any results

Comment: Hum would like to see your code. Or can you rename 'created_by' by 'user_id', then you can remove foreign keys and it will automatically detect the foreign key because it matches the Model name.